# haproxy suspends health checks if DNS resolution fails

Tags: mqtt, haproxy

We are using `haproxy` to switch between a local MQTT broker and a cloud broker based on availability (with preference to the local server). `haproxy.cfg` looks something like this:

```
global
  log 127.0.0.1   local1
  maxconn 1000
  daemon
  debug
  #quiet
  tune.bufsize 1024576
  stats socket /var/run/haproxy.sock mode 600 level admin

defaults
  log     global
  mode    tcp
  option  tcplog
  retries 3
  option redispatch

  timeout connect 5000
  timeout client 50000
  timeout server 50000

# Listen to all MQTT requests (port 1883)
listen mqtt
  bind *:1883

  mode tcp

  balance first  # Connect to first available

  timeout client  3h
  timeout server  3h
  option clitcpka
  option srvtcpka


  # MQTT server 1 - local wifi
  server wifi_broker localserver.local:1883 init-addr libc,last,none check inter 3s rise 5 fall 2 maxconn 1000 on-marked-up shutdown-backup-sessions on-marked-down shutdown-sessions

  # MQTT server 2 - cloud
  server aws_iot xxxxx.amazonaws.com:8883 backup check backup ssl verify none ca-file ./root-CA.crt crt ./cert.pem inter 5s rise 3 fall 2

listen stats
  bind :9000
  mode http
  stats enable  # Enable stats page
  stats hide-version  # Hide HAProxy version
  stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics  # Title text for popup window
  stats uri /haproxy_stats  # Stats URI
```

Everything works fine if the local broker is available when `haproxy` starts up. However, if the wifi connection to the local machine is down when haproxy starts up, `init-addr none` still allows it to start using the backup server (aws_iot). The local server is marked as "Down for Maintenance" and no more health checks are performed. Even after the network is up and running, `haproxy` is unaware of it and does not switch back from the cloud server.

Is there any way to make it consider unresolved domain name the same as a normal "down" condition?

One alternative I see right now is to have a script polling the domain name in the background and sending an "enable server" command to the `haproxy` control socket once it is up. This seems overly roundabout for something that should be really simple!

Update:
Running the command `echo "enable server mqtt/wifi_server" | socat /var/run/haproxy.sock stdio` doesn't switch the backends after the local connection is up and running. `haproxy` just never switches back to the local server with anything short of restarting it.

Update 2:
Changed `init-addr none` to `init-addr libc,last,none`

Answer (score 0):

You are using "*init-addr none*" so the server will start without any valid IP address when it is in a down state.   In addition, your current config makes HAProxy able to resolve hostnames **only** at startup as mentioned [here](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#5.3).
So to make HAProxy resolves *localserver.local* after startup to get right the IP and send health checks you need to configure a [resolvers section](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#5.3.2) in HAProxy.

Comment: I guess I should update the question. I did change it `init-addr libc,last,none`. `haproxy` connects to the right one if I restart it after the wifi connection is up .

As for resolvers, do I have hardcode the local IP of the wifi router for the local hostname to resolve?

Comment: Yes the DNS IP should be hardcoded to avoid the "chicken or the egg" problem.  
`init-addr libc,last,none` won't resolve your problem too if *localserver* is not resolvable when the wifi is down. But if you put it in your */etc/hosts* it should work.  
More about [init-addr](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#init-addr)